# Simple Modelica Libraries

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am fairly new to modelica. I would like to know if there are any simple libraries that are easily understandable available for download? Libraries that have examples whose total equations do not go beyond 100 or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the IntroductoryExamples library available with SystemModeler. It shows some of the important parts of building your own library. There's a guide that will guide you through the process called [Getting Started](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/getting-started/system-modeler-getting-started.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

You could try DrModelica in OpenModelica Notebook. It comes with OpenModelica and is sort of interactive Modelica tutorial. Just start OpenModelica Notebook.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I have gone through the OMNotebook examples. I was wondering if there are anything else available which are fairly simple

Answer (score 4):

My book, "[Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com/)", is available for free online.  In the second part, "Object-Oriented Modeling", you'll find a complete discussions of how to build connectors, components, packages, subsystems and architectures.